# How to implement number comparison like in the native iPhone contacts app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, comparison, contacts, phone-number

I want to compare two numbers, like in case, for e.g. the `number` is `987654`. 
It can be saved as `+91 987654` or `0987654`. But while `searching` or `comparing`, the number exactly matches and shows properly.

Right now I am using this code to compare the exact number. How do I enhance it?

```
// Remove non numeric characters from the phone number
phoneNumber = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^(id record, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue( (__bridge ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    BOOL result = NO;
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++) {
        NSString *contactPhoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
        contactPhoneNumber = [[contactPhoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:     [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
//Comparing the string are equal. phoneNumber is the number I am comparing to. 
        if ([contactPhoneNumber isEqualToString:phoneNumber])  {
            result = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
    return result;
}];
```

The above code results YES, only if the contactPhoneNumber and phoneNumber are exactly same. 
Not when `0987654` or `+91 987654` with `987654`.

The same thing works in WhatsApp number comparison too. 
Can anyone give any leads?

Comment: Please provide more information about when two numbers are equivalent. I don’t understand from your single example how to decide whether two given phone numbers are the same. Stripping leading zeroes, removing country codes… please include a complete list of the steps that need to be taken to normalize a number.

Comment: Amol, you might want to consider using the Google phone number library https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS that is very good at parsing, formatting, comparing phone numbers. This library should handle a lot of common and obscure cases.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I know that this isn't the neatest code, but...

```
NSString *originalPhoneNumber = [insert phone String];
int phoneNumber = [originalPhoneNumber intValue];
NSString *phoneFormatOne;//This will be your number formatted like 0987654
NSString *phoneFormatTwo;//This will be your number formatted like +91 987654
int phoneNumberFormatOne = [phoneFormatOne intValue];
NSString *partOne = [phoneFormatTwo substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,3)];
NSString *partTwo = [phoneFormatTwo substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4,10)];
int phoneNumberFormatTwo = [partOne intValue]*1000000 + [partTwo intValue];
```

Now you have all three in integer format, called phoneNumber, phoneNumberFormatOne, and phoneNumberFormatTwo. You can now just compare integers with an == in a if statement.